# Why does Chrome send so many HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a barebones Nodejs server only using the HTTP module. I've created an HTTP server and am listening on socket connections and on requests. I noticed that when I use chrome and go to localhost, three sockets connect, and two requests are made to "/". I know that, using some other webservers, I've seen Chrome request the same thing multiple times if it does not receive a quick response (about 5 seconds), but I am sending a response right away and still Chrome is connecting/requesting multiple times.

Is this expected, and if it is, should I be expected to handle duplicate requests?

My relevant code

```
    let server = http.createServer();
    server.listen({
        host: host,
        port: port
    });
    server.on('connection', function(socket){
         // gets printed 3 times
         console.log('connection')
    });
    server.on('request', function(request, response){
        // gets printed two times
        console.log('hi')
        // yet chrome only receives one response (seemingly)
        response.end('hi')
    });
```

Edit: Half solved. Now I am printing `request.url` and I see 
`/`
and
`favicon.ico`

So there are 2 requests, but still 3 socket connections. I guess every single request is on a new socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All individual images, css and javascript will definitely make http requests. No doubt about it.